# Faulty string representation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very, very new to Python and I figured I could do a simple app to parse an xml format for me. The problem is, it almost looks like I'm getting invalid elements from the `element.getElementsByTagName()` method. I'll attach all related source code below.

The problem arises when trying to format the data that I capture from the XML; the error code is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/development/xml2dnf/main.py", line 8, in <module> output_file.write(str(result))
        File "C:\development\xml2dnf\Shotsheet.py", line 18, in __str__ reply += str(shot) + "\n"
        File "C:\development\xml2dnf\StaticShot.py", line 19, in __str__ self.rect[2], self.rect[3])
ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name
```

I attempted to fiddle around with the reported problematic line until I figured that the error might not be there. As I went up my hierarchy, I noticed that if I tell one of my classes to *not* parse a specific list I send to it, it works almost as expected. When I don't parse the aformentioned, the error magically goes away.

Thinking that a pair of classes of mine were the problem, I went to them and did all I could to locate an alleviate that stray '{'. I found no problems.

I tried to troubleshoot, going up until the xml itself. I printed it and it looked okay. However, when I printed the results I should have gotten, I noticed that it prints some strange, invalid values and then prints what I should have gotten should the error not be present.

I did some Google searches, but I could find very little on this issue. Whatever I could find either didn't alleviate my problem or was inconsequential. I've exhausted my troubleshooting, considering also that I'm new to the language.

---

UPDATE:

After messing around with XML, I noticed that the invalid elements were a result of me not understanding how `getElementsById` works. The method returns *all* elements with the ID as opposed to just those who are direct children of the element. Tweaking the implementation solved the issue.

Now that I got that out of the way, I'm still getting the aforementioned error. The only thing I can think of is that my `__str__` implementation for my classes is faulty, but I still fail to see how. Printing every single parameter on its own yields the expected results, but using `__str__` fails miserably and the error helps me not in any conceivable way.

For the sake of illustration, here's the code the interpreter says is at fault:

```
def __str__(self):
        reply = "ShotData\x7Bid = {0} rect = ({1}, {2}, {3}, {4}) ".format(self.index, self.rect[0], self.rect[1],
                                                                           self.rect[2], self.rect[3])
        if self.render != 'ALPHA':
            reply += "render = {0} ".format(self.render)

        if self.collision >= 0:
            reply += "collision = {0} ".format(self.collision)

        if self.fixed_angle:
            reply += "fixed_angle = true angular_velocity = {0}\x7D".format(self.angular_velocity)

        delay_string = str(self.delay_color)
        reply += "delay_color = {0} ".format(delay_string)

        return reply
```

The code that calls it:

```
def __str__(self):
        reply = "#UserShotData\n\nshot_image = {0}\ndelay_rect=({1}, {2}, {3}, {4})\n\n"

        for shot in self.shot_array:
            reply += str(shot) + "\n"

        delay_x1 = self.delay_rect[0]
        delay_y1 = self.delay_rect[1]
        delay_x2 = self.delay_rect[2]
        delay_y2 = self.delay_rect[3]

        return reply.format(self.shot_image, delay_x1, delay_y1, delay_x2, delay_y2)
```

And the instruction that asks for the string representation:

```
output_file.write(str(result))
```

As always, any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is too much code here.  Can you reduce it to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @larsks I have promptly updated the question as the nature of the error has shifted. I also minimized the amount of code shown to a bare minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that writing `ShotData\x7Bid` is exactly the same as writing `ShotData{Bid`, using an escape sequence here doesn't cause `.format` to treat the curly brace any different. If you want to escape a curly brace, you need to double it:

```
reply = "ShotData{{id = {0} rect = ({1}, {2}, {3}, {4}) ".format(self.index, self.rect[0], self.rect[1], self.rect[2], self.rect[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the format line. The `\x7B` character breaks it. If you want to insert curly brackets in a formatted string, I suggest you do it afterwards :

```
 reply = "{0} rect = ({1}, {2}, {3}, {4})   ".format(self.index, self.rect[0], self.rect[1], self.rect[2],self.rect[3])
 reply = "ShotData{Bid = " + reply
```